# Retornar string XML em WCF

Tags: xml, wcf

Eu preciso enviar o resultado deste XML por um metodo WCF.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Siape>
<matricula>8707350</matricula>
<matricula_inst />
<nome>SOLANGE ALMEIDA MORAES</nome>
<data_nascimento>06/01/1961</data_nascimento>
<cargo>035</cargo>
<tipo>Servidor</tipo>
<num_orgao>36207</num_orgao>
<nome_orgao>AGENCIA NACIONAL DE VIGILANCIA SANITARIA</nome_orgao>
<margem>0,19</margem>
<margem_cartao>454,20</margem_cartao>
<saldo_devedor>44,00</saldo_devedor>
<emprestimos>
<num_rubrica>34116</num_rubrica>
<nome_rubrica>BB</nome_rubrica>
<valor_emprestimo>0,00</valor_emprestimo>
<valor_parcela>1.112,87</valor_parcela>
<qtd_parcelas>96</qtd_parcelas>
<qtd_parcelas_aberto>80</qtd_parcelas_aberto>
<contrato>845575496</contrato>
<banco>BB</banco>
</emprestimos>
<emprestimos>
<num_rubrica>34123</num_rubrica>
<nome_rubrica>BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO</nome_rubrica>
<valor_emprestimo>0,00</valor_emprestimo>
<valor_parcela>313,32</valor_parcela>
<qtd_parcelas>96</qtd_parcelas>
<qtd_parcelas_aberto>79</qtd_parcelas_aberto>
<contrato>542771688</contrato>
<banco>ITAU</banco>
</emprestimos>
<emprestimos>
<num_rubrica>34123</num_rubrica>
<nome_rubrica>BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO</nome_rubrica>
<valor_emprestimo>0,00</valor_emprestimo>
<valor_parcela>300,97</valor_parcela>
<qtd_parcelas>96</qtd_parcelas>
<qtd_parcelas_aberto>79</qtd_parcelas_aberto>
<contrato>548271401</contrato>
<banco>ITAU</banco>
</emprestimos>
<emprestimos>
<num_rubrica>34123</num_rubrica>
<nome_rubrica>BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO</nome_rubrica>
<valor_emprestimo>0,00</valor_emprestimo>
<valor_parcela>992,31</valor_parcela>
<qtd_parcelas>96</qtd_parcelas>
<qtd_parcelas_aberto>79</qtd_parcelas_aberto>
<contrato>548671154</contrato>
<banco>ITAU</banco>
</emprestimos>
</Siape>
```

Tentei enviar o XML como string

```
public string ConsultaSiapeEmprestimo(string usuario, string senha, string cpf, string matricula, string tipo)
```

Mas ao enviar os dados, o WCF devolve desta maneira:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header />
  <s:Body>
    <ConsultaSiapeEmprestimoResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <ConsultaSiapeEmprestimoResult>&lt;?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?&gt;&lt;Siape&gt;
&lt;matricula&gt;8707350&lt;/matricula&gt;
&lt;matricula_inst /&gt;
&lt;nome&gt;SOLANGE ALMEIDA MORAES&lt;/nome&gt;
&lt;data_nascimento&gt;06/01/1961&lt;/data_nascimento&gt;
&lt;cargo&gt;035&lt;/cargo&gt;
&lt;tipo&gt;Servidor&lt;/tipo&gt;
&lt;num_orgao&gt;36207&lt;/num_orgao&gt;
&lt;nome_orgao&gt;AGENCIA NACIONAL DE VIGILANCIA SANITARIA&lt;/nome_orgao&gt;
&lt;margem&gt;0,19&lt;/margem&gt;
&lt;margem_cartao&gt;454,20&lt;/margem_cartao&gt;
&lt;saldo_devedor&gt;44,00&lt;/saldo_devedor&gt;
&lt;emprestimos&gt;
&lt;num_rubrica&gt;34116&lt;/num_rubrica&gt;
&lt;nome_rubrica&gt;BB&lt;/nome_rubrica&gt;
&lt;valor_emprestimo&gt;0,00&lt;/valor_emprestimo&gt;
&lt;valor_parcela&gt;1.112,87&lt;/valor_parcela&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas&gt;96&lt;/qtd_parcelas&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;80&lt;/qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;
&lt;contrato&gt;845575496&lt;/contrato&gt;
&lt;banco&gt;BB&lt;/banco&gt;
&lt;/emprestimos&gt;
&lt;emprestimos&gt;
&lt;num_rubrica&gt;34123&lt;/num_rubrica&gt;
&lt;nome_rubrica&gt;BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO&lt;/nome_rubrica&gt;
&lt;valor_emprestimo&gt;0,00&lt;/valor_emprestimo&gt;
&lt;valor_parcela&gt;313,32&lt;/valor_parcela&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas&gt;96&lt;/qtd_parcelas&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;79&lt;/qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;
&lt;contrato&gt;542771688&lt;/contrato&gt;
&lt;banco&gt;ITAU&lt;/banco&gt;
&lt;/emprestimos&gt;
&lt;emprestimos&gt;
&lt;num_rubrica&gt;34123&lt;/num_rubrica&gt;
&lt;nome_rubrica&gt;BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO&lt;/nome_rubrica&gt;
&lt;valor_emprestimo&gt;0,00&lt;/valor_emprestimo&gt;
&lt;valor_parcela&gt;300,97&lt;/valor_parcela&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas&gt;96&lt;/qtd_parcelas&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;79&lt;/qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;
&lt;contrato&gt;548271401&lt;/contrato&gt;
&lt;banco&gt;ITAU&lt;/banco&gt;
&lt;/emprestimos&gt;
&lt;emprestimos&gt;
&lt;num_rubrica&gt;34123&lt;/num_rubrica&gt;
&lt;nome_rubrica&gt;BANCO ITAU CONSIGNADO&lt;/nome_rubrica&gt;
&lt;valor_emprestimo&gt;0,00&lt;/valor_emprestimo&gt;
&lt;valor_parcela&gt;992,31&lt;/valor_parcela&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas&gt;96&lt;/qtd_parcelas&gt;
&lt;qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;79&lt;/qtd_parcelas_aberto&gt;
&lt;contrato&gt;548671154&lt;/contrato&gt;
&lt;banco&gt;ITAU&lt;/banco&gt;
&lt;/emprestimos&gt;
&lt;/Siape&gt;</ConsultaSiapeEmprestimoResult>
    </ConsultaSiapeEmprestimoResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Como posso devolver da maneira correta?

Answer (score 1):

O melhor seria deixar o WCF serializar o seu XML. Para isso você deve gerar uma classe com a estrutura próxima do resultado XML que deseja retornar, por exemplo:

```
public class Siape
{
    public int matricula { get; set; }
    public string matricula_inst { get; set; }  
    // e todas as outras propriedades  
}
```

E seu serviço deve retornar essa classe.

```
public Siape ConsultaSiapeEmprestimo(string usuario, string senha, string cpf, string matricula, string tipo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Isso é normal acontecer.
Para não haver conflitos do conteúdo a transferir com o pacote SOAP que é criado, a framework automaticamente (e muito bem) faz o escape dos caracteres que podem criar conflitos.

Apesar da mensagem aparecer assim, no lado do cliente quando receber a informação deverá aparecer tudo normalmente.